# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'openModal' of undefined at onClick React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

I am getting

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'openModal' of undefined
        at onClick
```

with the following react component:

```
class ReactReduxTabs extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
      this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
      this.render_response_json_modal = this.render_response_json_modal.bind(this);
      this.state = {tabIndex: 1, isModelOpen: false, modalText: "blah blah blah"};
  }

  openModal() {
    console.log("open modal");
    this.setState({ isModalOpen: true })
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.setState({ isModalOpen: false })
  }

  render_response_json_modal(headers, target_header) {
      return add_rendering(
          headers,
          target_header,
          function(val, row) {
              return (<p onClick={() => {this.openModal()} }>yaaaaaaa</p>)
          }
      )
  }

render() {

      if (orderMetricsFetched == true) {

        order_metrics.error_report_failed_orders.headers = this.render_response_json_modal(order_metrics.error_report_failed_orders.headers, 'RESPONSE', this.openModal)

        return (

<div className="card">
                      <ReduxDataTable data={order_metrics.error_report_failed_orders}/>
                    </div>
```

What `add_rendering` does is take something like

```
headers = ['Header 1', 'Header 2']
```

and if you target Header 1 change to

```
headers= [
  {title: 'Header 1', render: function() { ...returns what should go in the table cell...} },
  'Header 2'
]
```

The issue seems to be with the `this` context as the table cell is clicked. When the table cell is clicked, it should call the component's `openModal` method.

The good new is it's very close, the table renders as it should, with each `RESPONSE` column cell having the random 'yaaaaa' inside, proving the `add_rendering` of `render_response_json_modal` worked. There are no errors until I click on each `RESPONSE` cell (one of the 'yaaaa'), where I see this print in console:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here:

```
return (<p onClick={() => {this.openModal()} }>yaaaaaaa</p>)
```

`this` refers to the function scope not the outer scope (that is what you want), a quick fix is to save a reference of `this` outside the function and use that.

```
var self = this;   
return add_rendering(
  headers,
  target_header,
  function(val, row) {
     return (<p onClick={() => {self.openModal()} }>yaaaaaaa</p>)
  })
);
```

By the way, the exception says that `this` is undefined inside the function probably because you're using `"use strict"` mode.

Comment: you are a God of react

Comment: actually i've never used react but this error is quite common with javascript   ;)